# Java NIO on Android: Attempting to READ/WRITE while connection is still pending?

Tags: android, networking, nio

This question regards Java's NIO on Android (2.2, though I can build for higher APIs if necessary): After performing a SocketChannel connect() to a destination IP address, I register my channel for a READ operation. The problem is that when I try to perform a READ on the resulting selected key set, I receive NotYetConnectedException. While I can check the channel's status with isConnectionPending before I try to READ, I would ideally like to have READ keys be selected only when the connection is actually working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

While the connection is pending, the channel must only be registered for `OP_CONNECT`.

When `OP_CONNECT` fires, you must call `finishConnect()`, and then proceed as follows:

1. If it returns true, you must then deregister `OP_CONNECT`, and you may then register `OP_READ` or `OP_WRITE`.
2. If it returns false, do nothing: the connection is still pending.
3. If it throws an exception, the connect has failed and you must close the channel.

Comment: how deregister `OP_CONNECT` ?

Comment: I think `key.interestOps(0)` should work. You can directly switch to OP_READ or OP_WRITE `key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ)`